# Symfony 5 - refresh user session without relogging

Tags: symfony

Is there any way to refresh `User` session? I have my controller with change locale form, once it submitted i want to refresh that session with new set locale. I already tried to use session `migrate()` ,but unsuccessfully.

Any ideas?

Part of my controller

```
/**
    * @route("/changeLocale", name="changeLocale")
    */
    public function changeLocale(Request $request, Session $session)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
            ->add('locale', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Français' => 'fr_FR',
                    'Czech' => 'cs_CZ',
                    'English(US)' => 'en_US'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm()
        ;

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $locale = $form->getData()['locale'];
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $user->setLocale($locale);
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            $session->migrate();
        }

        return $this->render('admin/dashboard/locale.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the wrong way.
When you authenticate, you save the locale of your user entity in the session. Right? If you have a LocaleSubscriber that saves the locale in your session, recreating your session won't work. The locale is only saved in the session at authentication.
If you change the locale, you just need to update the session.

```php
        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $locale = $form->getData()['locale'];
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $user->setLocale($locale);
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            // Update the session
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        }
```

Comment: Oh, clear explanation, thanks you so much!!